# Meteor form elements cause rerender and inputs are not preserved when calling Accounts.createUser

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I built a custom form for creating new users in Meteor.

```
<button id="hide-show">Hide/show registration form</button>

<div class="wrapper" style="display:none">
  <form>
    // some inputs, each with an id.
  </form>
  <button id="create-account">Create account</button>
</div>
```

In my js my for the template I use jQuery .toggle() to hide/show the div wrapping the form when the #hide-show button is clicked. I also call Accounts.createUser when #create-account is clicked.

First of all, as long as there is a form wrapping the inputs, the whole page seems to be rerendered when I call Accounts.createUser. At least all elements with an original display equal to none gets hidden, regardless of their current display attribute when the call was made. (I tried this with a bootstrap modal too. The modal disappears when I call Accounts.createUser.) However, removing the form element and just leaving the inputs fixes this problem (but breaks the css of the form since bootstrap expects inputs to be wrapped in form elements for certain behaveior).

Secondly, even if I dont have a form element wrapping the inputs they are not preserved when  Accounts.createUser causes an error (username taken etc). I obviously dont want to force the user to retype their registration info. I have preserve-inputs installed and I even tried wrapping the inputs in {{#constant}} but without any luck.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I run Accounts.createUser on the client. I dont call it with Meteor.call or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hiding the div right away you could hide it on a successful account creation. I've done something similar, it's still a work in progress hope it helps

My signup template:

```
<template name="SignUpForm">    
    <div id="signUpForm" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3>Sign Up</h3>
        </div>
        <form><div class="modal-body" align="center">
            <input type="text" id="usernameSU" placeholder="Username" /><br />
            <input type="password" id="passwordSU" placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <input type="password" id="passconf" placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="You@Email.com" /><br />
            {{> CurErr}}
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>
        </div></form> 
    </div>
</template>
```

the CurErr template just displays anything in the curErr Session variable in a bootstrap alert.
my signup template.js:

```
Template.SignUpForm.events({
'click #btnSignUp': function(e,t){
    signUpUser();
}
});

function signUpUser(){
    var password = $('#passwordSU').val();
    var passconf = $('#passconf').val();

    if (password !== passconf){
        Session.set('curErr', 'Password fields do not match');

    } else {
        var options = {
            username: $('#usernameSU').val(),
            password: $('#passwordSU').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            profile: {}
        }



        try{
            //made a validation library, use your own validation logic here
            validate(options.username, 'username');
            validate(options.password, 'password');
            validate(options.email, 'email');

            Accounts.createUser(options, function(err){
                if(err){
                    Session.set('curErr', err.reason);
                }
                else
                    $('#signUpForm').modal('hide');
            });
        }catch(err){
            Session.set('curErr', err.reason);
        }
    }
}
```

So my signup modal gets hidden on a successful user creation otherwise I display the error right on the form and the user doesn't lose any data, also if the form is closed the data is still preserved when its reopened.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and it turned out that I was using Meteor.logginIn() in the helper of a high level template to display a loading page.

It appears that Meteor goes in to a logginIn state even if Accounts.createUser fails. When it does it causes the loading template to render and then it comes back out of the loggingIn state and causes the other template to render. Being that it is hosted locally and there is no connection latency, all this happens so fast that you never even see the loading template render and are just left confused as to why everything just flickers and disappears.

The only solution is to use Meteor.logginIn() at a lower level template that doesn't affect the rest of the templates and cause them to re-render.

Ideally Accounts.createUser would not set Meteor.loggingIn to a true state unless account creation succeeded.

I've filed a issue on github ([Issue #1243](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1243)), but unfortunately I wouldn't expect this to be a priority issue.